# How to disable or customize Qt File Dialog?

Tags: xfce, qt

I'm using Debian with XFCE. I've got lots of applications that opens a file dialog from Qt (I think) (for example Chromium, Xfce4-screenshooter, etc) that has a "search" facility which I find totally unusable:

[image]

How can I use the "default" file dialog (ie. when I clicked "open file" within Libreoffice) for all applications:

[image]

...or at least just disable the "search" behaviour of Qt file dialog?

Comment: Look in this thread - https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/54ocjq/why_cant_applications_call_on_the_desktop_ui_to/.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, except in reverse: after updating to OpenSuSE 15.5/XFCE, I found the new GTK file open dialog unusable because of its [switch to search-as-you-type instead of type-ahead](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324718/229607). So I followed slm's link to the Reddit post, and tried

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=kde
```

before launching the desired app (in my case it was QtCreator).
That's all that was needed. Now I have a properly working file chooser with type-ahead search. No need to add anything to system-wide files like `.xinitrc`.

Caveat: this will probably only work with Qt apps.

> Qt has always been pretty good at utilizing native platform tools.
> Even on Windows you have a proper file dialog. GTK, on the other hand,
> has always been rather dumb in that regard. I don't know if GTK
> developers simply don't use file dialogs at all or have some spartan
> ancestry, but their file dialog is as ugly as it is useless due to
> many missing features and no integration with the platform.

© [phoerious](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/54ocjq/comment/d89fh53/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 0):

This is explained pretty well in this Arch Linux wiki page titled: [Environment Variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_variables#Examples), specifically in the Examples section:

> The following section lists a number of common environment variables used by a Linux system and describes their values.
>
> `DE` indicates the Desktop Environment being used. [`xdg-open`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open) will use it to choose more user-friendly file-opener application that desktop environment provides. Some packages need to be installed to use this feature. For [GNOME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME), that would be [libgnome](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libgnome/)<sup>AUR</sup>; for [Xfce](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce) this is [exo](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=exo). Recognised values of `DE` variable are: `gnome`, `kde`, `xfce`, `lxde` and `mate`.
>
> The `DE` environment variable needs to be exported before starting the window manager. For example:
>
> ```
> ~/.xinitrc
> export DE="xfce"
> exec openbox
> ```
>
> This will make `xdg-open` use the more user-friendly `exo-open`, because it assumes it is running inside Xfce. Use `exo-preferred-applications` for configuring.

Comment: I've no `~/.xinitrc` file, but I think it's the same as `~/.bashrc`. Anyway, after `export DE="xfce"`, I thought `xfce4-screenshooter` should open the gtk file dialog instead of Qt file dialog, but it still opens Qt file dialog. So I would say it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ceremcem - you have to create that file, they're not the same.

Comment: Creating `~/.xinitrc` with the content of `export DE="xfce"` and logging out/logging in still doesn't solve the issue (`.xinitrc` has executable flag)